# Java como fazer uma query nativa e retornar para uma lista de DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring

Estou utilizando o Spring Hibernate e estou tentando fazer uma consulta nativa com JOiN retornar para uma lista de DTO. Tentei utilizando o @Query(value="", nativeQuery=true) com uma List mas ele retorna os atributos serializados. também tentei com o @SqlResultSetMapping dentro do DTO, mas acho q essa não seria a maneira mais performática.

Comment: Consegui resolver utilizando o RowMapper<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Procure por [result transformer](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/). Eles foram feitos exatamente para
>   fazer o que você deseja e funciona com HQL e SQL (native query)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13782489/2387977

Se não conseguir, por algum motivo, existe outra maneira parecida com esta:

```
List resultado = s.createSQLQuery(
  "SELECT new SeuDto(st.name, st.age) FROM Student st ";
```

Em que você pode fazer um `new` do objeto direto no `select` e receber como resultado uma lista Object[] que serão instâncias de "SeuDto". Isto funciona desde que você tenha um construtor em "SeuDto" aceitando este parâmetros `name` e `age`, no caso do exemplo.